# Can't understand super's functionality in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, super

First off I'll show you my code:

```
public class Person {
String _name;
int _age;
public Person(String name, int age){
    _name = name;
    _age = age;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Age:" + _age + ". Name: " + _name;
  }
}

public class Principal extends Person{
String _gender;
int _rank;
public Principal(String name, int age, String gender, int rank){
    super(name, age);
    _gender = gender;
    _rank = rank;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Age:" + _age + " .Name: " + _name + " .Gender: " + _gender + " .Rank: " + _rank;
}
```

}

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Person me = new Person("Bob", 23);
    System.out.println(me);
    Principal hj = new Principal("Dan", 39, "Male", 1);
   }
}
```

I can't understand why I have to add the first 2 parameters in `Principal hj = new Principal("Dan", 39, "Male", 1);` . . . I thought that `super(name, age);` was supposed to inherit the first two parameters from the object `me` and I would only need to apply the last 2 parameters.

What am I miss-understanding?

Comment: If you don't specify those arguments, where is Java supposed to get them from? There is absolutely no relation between `me` and `hj`.

Comment: Using `_` as the first letter of an identifier hurts my eyes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that's what I've been asking myself, but then I was also getting tripped upon what the purpose of the super(...) was if I am re-specifying the parameters again

Comment: In your code if you are thinking that Person Object and Pricipal object have some relation automatically created, thats not true. bothe "me" and "hj" are totally different objects in your code.

Comment: I agree: those underscores are hideous... As is the lack of indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what super(...); does is call the super class constructor which takes that number and type parameters, depending on your super class constructor.

Then, you are mixing stuff, you inherit from the class, not from the instace of a class(objects), that means they share the attributes(every principle object has the attributes(name, age) that all Person object has, as Principle inherits from Person).

You are not converting a Person Object to a Principal Object(downcasting) because you can have unexpected behaviours, its risky. Then what you CAN do, are 2 things, you can upcast a Principal class into a Person class, then the attributes stay the same, and you can use all the common Person attributes.

Or, you can create a contructor in principal, which takes a Person object, and copies its attributes, then you could call it something like:

```
Person m = new Person("David", 12);
Principal hj = new Principal(m, "Male", 1);
```

Hope it clarifies!

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that super(name, age); was supposed to inherit the first two parameters from the object me and I would only need to apply the last 2 parameters.

What would that even mean?
The parameter values must come from *somewhere*.

---

`super(...)` simply calls the base class constructor, with whatever arguments you want to pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, `super()` invokes a constructor in the parent class.

The arguments you pass determine which constructor is invoked.

The parent class knows nothing about the arguments passed to the constructor in the sub-class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Person me = new Person("Bob", 23);
 Principal hj = new Principal("Dan", 39, "Male", 1);
```

Here you are creating two different objects. So, person "me" is a different object and Principal "hj" is another. Principal HJ will be having its own "instance" of Person as its parent. So, you have to pass all the parameters to hj so that this parent person instance gets two of them. And thats why you call super.

Answer (score 0):

nothing difficult..

super() call your parent class constructor, and give or add property, value for your child class.